# Adding new input fileds for attributes in a specific attribute group - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento, module, attributes, product, magento2

I created a new attribute group 'Features' in the products section. I need to create two new fields (checkbox and text field) apart from the available option for attributes inside the group 'Features'. I am a beginner in Magento so any help is really appreciated.

***Note: I need those extra fields for attributes inside the group 'Features' only***

Thanks in advance.

[image: Please check this screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use upgrade schema

```
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $tableName = $setup->getTable('catalog_eav_attribute');
            $connection = $setup->getConnection();
            $connection->addColumn(
                $tableName,
                'field_1',
                [
                    'type' => Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => '0',
                    'comment' => 'Label 1'
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain little more ?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-how-to-create-sql-setup-script.html